# how to do a postback and get value from my html in that postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a js function

```
function(id){
// do a postback here and get the id on the server side  
}
```

I need to send the **id** to the server, how could I do this?

any way will do, using additional/hidden controls anything

Comment: A multitude of ways, including but not limited to AJAX, HTTP POST, HTTP GET...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function(id){
    __doPostBack('', id);
}
```

On serverside you can access the argument via forms/params collection and the key `__EVENTARGUMENT` that is an autmatically generated HiddenField:

VB.Net:

```
Dim ID as String = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")
```

or C#:

```
string ID = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

[Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.2)

Comment: how am I going to get the id on the server side ?